# How to display Activity History in Created Date order in Lightning UI?

Tags: activities, activityhistory

In Lightning UI Activities are not in order of Created Date. In Classic UI in contrary they are in correct order.
The problem is in Time attribute. When two Tasks are created at the same Date but in different time - in Lightning UI shows first the Task which was created second and second goes the one which was created first. In Classic UI everything shows correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Activities are showing correctly according to the documentation - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activity_timeline_customization_considerations_lex.htm&type=5

> Items in the activity timeline are sorted by the effective date: the
> date and time the event happened. Tasks have a different sort order.
>
> 1. Completed tasks with either a due-date in the future, or no due date, are sorted by completion date.
> 2. Completed tasks with a due date in the past are sorted by their due date.
> 3. Tasks that aren’t marked complete, with due dates in the past, are sorted by their due-date and are marked overdue in the timeline.